# How to diagnose TeamCity / HSQLDB error [S1000][-25] ".data file is modified but .backup file does not exist

Tags: connection, teamcity, hsqldb

We are using a third party tool (TeamCity) that suddenly stopped working and shows a DB key/index type of error in their log files like this:

[image]

However, we are unable to simply connect to the HSQLDB database using the blank username (assume that is superuser) and password combed from log.  The error is:

[S1000][-25] error in script file line: 342 org.hsqldb.HsqlException: .data file is modified but .backup file does not exist.

I know almost nothing about the HSQLDB so apologize if this is obvious issue.

Comment: You could try to drop database completely and restart the server. The projects and build configurations will remain. Only users and build history will be dropped.

Comment: Thanks, but we don't even understand how to connect to it in order to drop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never did figure out how to connect to the database.  However we were able to resolve the duplicate key issue shown in the screenshot by editing the buildserver.script file.

The .script file is a text file containing SQL commands in it.  We surmised that file might be run during startup and noticed that some "insert" commands contained duplicate data.

The duplicate lines (~1000) were removed using NotePad++ by finding distinct lines and assuming that should be correct as the new file and then diffing the old vs new to make sure nothing else was lost as a side effect.

YouTrack started right up after that change.